# How to use the column name for comparison against a parameter in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What I am trying to achieve here is to pass in a day of week parameter, which holds the value of the current day(Wednesday, etc), and compare it against the column names to determine which column is to be used in the where clause.

So take columns Sunday - Saturday. In the where clause I want to compare those column names to the parameter I passed in and pull back ONLY the value for the match.

Say table below is called DayTable

```
Sunday  Monday  Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
   1       1        1       1       1       1       0
   1       1        1       1       1       1       1


SELECT *
FROM   DayTable
WHERE  ColumnName = @DayOfWeek
```

This is what I'm wanting to achieve if its even possible. I was looking at `ColumnProperty` but I don't think that's what I need.

Comment: tried to line up the 1's and 0's but format failed lol, just picture 2 rows, with those values and that is the data being used.

Comment: haha alright i didnt think this was as simple as i hoped. I'll just restructure the table to simplify it.

Comment: What would your expected output be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    CASE @DayOfWeek
        WHEN 'Sunday' THEN Sunday
        WHEN 'Monday' THEN Monday
        WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN Tuesday
        WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN Wednesday
        WHEN 'Thursday' THEN Thursday
        WHEN 'Friday' THEN Friday
        WHEN 'Saturday' THEN Saturday
    END AS TodaysValue
FROM
    DayTable;
```

Comment: +1 for the best performance (slightly), though I hope you don't mind that I fixed the syntax.

Comment: @TimLehner You didn't "Fix" the syntax, you changed it! Both are equally valid. :-)

Comment: Ah, yes, I did change to the simple form, though there were too many `case` declarations before.

Comment: This is exactly what i did hahaha, alot of valid answers here though wish i could mark them all :(. I could of changed the table structure but i wouldnt of gained anything with the rest of the data that went along with it on the back end. This solution solved it quick and easy!

Answer (score 5):

Since your data is not normalized, you can can use the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to get your data into rows which makes it easy to query:

```
select col, value
from DayTable
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in ([Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], 
              [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday])
) unpiv
where col = @DayOfWeek
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed7d61/1).

The best solution to your issue would be to redesign your table to something like this:

```
create table DayTable
(
   DayName varchar(20),
   Value int
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You **could** dynamically construct the necessary SQL and execute it using sp_executesql.

Please note that the following should have no space in `@ sql` but my stupid work proxy won't post that.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM DayTable WHERE ' + @DayOfWeek + ' = ' + @value
sp_executesql @sql
```

However, I don't think the SQL you have posted is right either. I think you want to only select the appropriate *column*

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @DayOfWeek + ' FROM DayTable'
sp_executesql @sql
```

However, I would suggest that your database design is not ideal - it would be much simpler to pivot this table like

```
Day     Value1     Value2
Monday     1          1
Tuesday    1          1
Wednesday  1          1
Thursday   1          1
Friday     1          1
Saturday   1          0
Sunday     1          1
```

Then you can simply do

```
SELECT Value1, Value2
FROM   DayTable
WHERE  Day = 'Thursday'
```